# How to change query parameters in Django filter?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I've created a multi field filter API using Django filter

My custom class based filter code is as below

```
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters

class EnquiryLogFilter(filters.FilterSet):

    start_date = filters.DateFilter(field_name='actual_mail_date',lookup_expr='gte')
    end_date = filters.DateFilter(field_name='actual_mail_date',lookup_expr='lte')
    broker_name = filters.CharFilter(field_name='broker_name')
    insured_name = filters.CharFilter(field_name='insured_name')


    class Meta:
        model = EnquiryLog
        fields =['start_date','end_date','broker_name','insured_name']
```

and my filter view is

```
class ENQUIRYFILTERVIEWSET(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    # comment this when using inbuilt get_queryset
    queryset = EnquiryLog.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EnquirySerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,OrderingFilter,SearchFilter,)

    filterset_class= EnquiryLogFilter

    ordering =  ('-unique_id_for_mail')
    search_fields = ('country_name')
```

now when I call my api in browser with various query parameters I am getting the result also

```
/di_enquirylog_filter_query/?start_date=2020-08-10&end_date=2020-08-30&broker_name=Broker-BPL+5&insured_name=
```

and my response

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
    {
        "unique_id_for_mail": "DISOMPO031",
        "actual_mail_date": "2020-08-30",
        "subject_name": "RE: Macquarie - Vedanta Prepay",
        "broker_name": "Broker-BPL 5",
        "is_today_mail": -2,
        "insured_name": "Mac Steel",
        "obligor_name": "ING Prosafe Nautipa",
        "country_name": "UK",
        "limit": "USD 45M",
        "is_enabled": "True"
    }
]
```

Until now everything is working fine, the above API works well for single query parameter or multi query parameter by keeping query parameter to blank I mean like below

```
.../di_enquirylog_filter_query/?start_date=2020-08-10&end_date=2020-08-30&broker_name=&insured_name=
```

Here you can see broker_name and insured_name are blank (I am using Django rest framework)

But when my developer hit the same api he says that for those parameters whose value is not given by user he will make it as null or "" or '' and api will become like this

```
/di_enquirylog_filter_query/?start_date=2020-08-10&end_date=2020-08-30&broker_name=""&insured_name=""
```

or

```
/di_enquirylog_filter_query/?start_date=2020-08-10&end_date=2020-08-30&broker_name=''&insured_name=''
```

or

```
/di_enquirylog_filter_query/?start_date=2020-08-10&end_date=2020-08-30&broker_name=null&insured_name=null
```

but in this case filter returns empty list, as i can understand Django -filter does filter on the basis of "" or '' or null in the db for which it gets nothing hence blank

My question is how to handle this situation in djnago -filter or is there any way I can catch URL and change it to

```
/di_enquirylog_filter_query/?start_date=2020-08-10&end_date=2020-08-30&broker_name=&insured_name=
```

then apply it to queryset

now problem is my developer says he can pass some value for some query parameters as  he will pass actual value and for some query parameter he will pass either "" or '' or null.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the really easy (and correct) answer is that you should put your foot forward and ask your front-end engineer to construct the proper URL.

I don't know how `django-filters` works, but here's some pseudo code to show the direction you can take:

```
broker_name = filters.CharFilter(
    field_name='broker_name').exclude(
    broker_name__exact='""').exclude(
    broker_name__exact="''")
```

or maybe look at [overriding the filters](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html#overriding-default-filters).